# After enabling SSL in Oracle user must log in twice

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, ssl, tls-1.2

I've enabled SSL for my Oracle 12c DB. The lsnr starts up fine and I can access it via a `sqlplus / as sysdba` (no password auth there, it's OS local). However, if I attempt to connect as a user which requires password authentication, then it fails the first time with the error `ORA-28864: SSL connection closed gracefully` and then prompts again for username/password. If I enter my username and password again, it works!

Why would this fail the first time but work the second? That behavior is so odd and really what I want to try to figure out.

Comment: There are a couple of things that might cause this. Can you generate a client-side trace file for your sqlplus login attempt?

Comment: @pmdba I've tried repeatedly to enable that by following these instructions (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/net/doc/NWTR23/ch3trc.htm) but no matter what I do it won't seem to write a trace file. I have other trace files that seem to live in the standard diag directory, but there are so many I wouldn't even know what to look for or in what file. If there really only are maybe a couple things that could cause a double log in, could I know what those are? Or any kind of documentation ... the issue is this isn't really something I can search for. Thank you!